# How to install dependencies for module elevation (SRTM data)?

Tags: python, installation, dependencies, elevation, srtm

I would like to use the module [elevation](http://elevation.bopen.eu/en/stable/quickstart.html) (Python) to download SRTM1 images. I installed the module elevation. But now I have this when I enter `eio selfcheck`:

```
> u'GNU Make' not found or not usable. 
> u'unzip' not found or not usable.
> u'gunzip' not found or not usable.

> u'gdal_translate' not found or not usable.
> u'gdalbuildvrt' not found or not usable
```

I installed GNU make, but I'm not sure if it's correct. I have the module gdal_translate and gdalbuildvrt in the directory: C:\OSGeo4W64\bin. Should I move them somewhere else? And are GNU make, unzip, gunzip, gdal_translate, gdalbuildvrt modules or .exe?

Comment: I have this exact same issue; did you ever get it resolved @Suge?